# how can i limit the number of executions of fadeIn () and fadeOut () functions in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein, fadeout

I'v applied some fadeIn()/fadeOut() functions to my webpage,which are executed on mouseenter/mouseleave, but I'v noticed that if I drag in and drag out the cursor really fast for a multiple times the selected block keeps to appear/disapear for a few seconds after.

I'v tried to google some JQuery functions to fix it, but I haven't found anything.

```
 $('.navbar').mouseenter(function () {
 $(".context-box__blur").fadeIn(200).css('display', 'inline-block');
 $("span").fadeIn(200).css('display', 'inline-block');
});
 $('.navbar').mouseleave(function () {
 $("span").fadeOut(200);
 $(".context-box__blur").fadeOut(200);
});
```

How can fix it, or how can I limit the quantity of the function's executions by time?

Comment: Take a look at [`stop()`](https://api.jquery.com/stop/)

Answer (score 0):

`fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` has a `complete` function that runs after fadeIn/fadeOut completed, you may disable fadein or out before the ohter one is not completed:

```
var wait = false;

function fadeOut()
{
    if(wait) return false; // previous action not complete, cancel fadeOut
    wait = true;
    $("span").fadeOut(200, function(){ wait = false; })
}

function fadeIn()
{
    if(wait) return false; // previous action not complete, cancel fadeIn
    wait = true;
    $("span").fadeIn(200, function(){ wait = false; })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the way how `mouseenter()` & `mouseleave()` works. Try using `mouseover()`& `mouseout()` instead.

```
$("p").mouseover(function(){
    $("p").css("background-color", "yellow");
  });

  $("p").mouseout(function(){
    $("p").css("background-color", "lightgray");
  });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/GR8sk/

This JSFiddle will give you a clear idea on how these mouse events work.